# JavaScript unit test results in MSTest

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest, qunit

I have been asked to move unit-test results from QUnit to MSTest, as it became clear for the project lead today that there were in fact unit test on the user interface.
However, I would very much like not to write a new MS test for every case in the QUnit test file as this will increase maintanance required. I've added WatiN and expect to be able to get test results with that tool.

The obvious and simple solution would be to just use a single unit-test and make it list the tests that failed and let the debuggers figure it out. 
Skipping this solution, is there a way to register more test results from a single test runtime in MSTest? Possibly generate a dynamic unit-test assembly?

Any other possible and hopefully simple solutions?

edit: I switched to Chutzpah, which works approximately one thousand times better than WatiN.
Note that this has to work on the build server as well.
At this point I have one test that will fail if any one of the qunit tests fail.
I cannot use Visual Studio extensions as this has to work on the build server as well as locally.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I fully understand the question, but if you mean you want some way to run the qunit tests from within Visual Studio, there is an extension for Visual Studio called [Chutzpah](http://chutzpah.codeplex.com/) that can do this for you.

Sorry if I am barking up the wrong tree :)

Comment: Yes, I have switched to Chutzpah, and it works a lot better, but I can't add visual studio extensions as this has to work on the build server as well.

Comment: Ah, bummer. In theory it is possible [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/07/09/javascript-unit-tests-on-team-foundation-service-with-chutzpah.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage] but apparently doesn;t work for everyone. I will ask out TFS guru when he gets back from his holidays